# Identity server authorization based on user roles

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, claims-based-identity, user-roles

Identity server token generation successfully based on user roles when I set headers controller it's working in localhost when I am tried host in IIS server its give response like unauthorized user

Help me out how to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the exact response.

Comment: 401 unauthorized

Comment: Please give some code, screenshots and etc.

Comment: app.UseMvc();
app.UseAuthentication();
To this...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();

if change this issue fixed